# Apache: Inherit rewrite rules and defined variables

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have lots of typical vhosts sections that differ in one or two parameters in mod_rewrite rules, for example:

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    RewriteRule someurl/(.*)\.html /var/www/somepath1/file.$1.html [L]
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    RewriteRule someurl/(.*)\.html /var/www/somepath2/file.$1.html [L]
    ...
</VirtualHost>
...
```

I have found *InheritBefore* option in the Apache 2.4 so now I can do like this:

httpd.conf

```
RewriteRule someurl/(.*)\.html /var/www/somepath/file.$1.html [L]
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    RewriteOptions InheritBefore
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    RewriteOptions InheritBefore
    ...
</VirtualHost>
...
```

It looks more concise but there is a problem. I need to change *somepath* in the base rule to some variable. I have tried like this:

```
RewriteRule someurl/(.*)\.html /var/www/${somepath}/file.$1.html [L]
<VirtualHost *>
    Define somepath somepath1
    RewriteOptions InheritBefore
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
RewriteRule someurl/(.*)\.html /var/www/%{ENV:somepath}/file.$1.html [L]
<VirtualHost *>
    Define somepath somepath1
    RewriteOptions InheritBefore
    RewriteRule . - [E=somepath:somepath1]
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

but none of this works. Is any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second version may work if you use `SetEnv` instead of `Define`:

```
RewriteRule someurl/(.*)\.html /var/www/%{ENV:somepath}/file.$1.html [L]
<VirtualHost *>
    SetEnv somepath somepath1
    RewriteOptions InheritBefore
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Or, sometimes you have to use `SetEnvIf` instead of `SetEnv`, since `SetEnvIf` is processed earlier. For example:

```
    SetEnvIf Request_URI . somepath=somepath1
```

Otherwise you could use [mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html):

```
<Macro rewrite $path>
  RewriteRule someurl/(.*)\.html /var/www/$path/file.$1.html [L]
</Macro>
<Virtualhost *>
  Use rewrite somepath1
</Virtualhost>
```